# How to extract comments and star ratings from the yelp using DOM xpath in php

Tags: php, xpath

I have used this link of https://www.yelp.com/biz/cuisine-of-nepal-san-francisco.

Please suggest,extract comments and star ratings values using DOMXPath in PHP? I have tried somethig like this: 
    Thanks in Advance.

```
$result='https://www.yelp.com/biz/cuisine-of-nepal-san-francisco';//url
$html = file_get_contents($result);
libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
$doc = new DOMDocument; $doc->loadHTML( $html);//get htmlcontent
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);
$tag=array('ratingValue','review');
foreach($tag as $tags) {
    $tag_stuct=array('div','span','meta');//using html tags name
    foreach($tag_stuct as $tag_div) {
        $node1 = $xpath->query( '//'.$tag_div.'[@itemprop="'.$tags.'"]');
        $j=0;
        foreach($node1 as $ke) {
            $j++;
        }
        for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++) {
            if($node->item($i)->nodeValue !='') {
                $comments = $node->item($i)->nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using the API? https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business_reviews

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea.....